# Is it possible to generate example JSON from OpenApiSchema

Tags: openapi.net

I would like to generate the JSON example from OpenApiSchema. Is there any existing function or any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net

This help you yo generate random data based on schema

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).